# Runtime switch the schema in PostgreSQL using JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I am using JPA to manage the PostgreSQL database. Multiple schemas are present in DB. Due to product requirement we need fetch the data from different schemas as per input request. I managed to fetch the data from public schema.

But I couldn't find a solution to configure the JPA so that it will switch the Schemas and fetch the data at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

If the table names are different across schemas, the easiest way is to setup a default `search_path` for the user:

```
alter user your_user set search_path = public,schema_one,schema_two,schema_four;
```

Once you have done that, tables are searched along the schemas in the search_path.

Again: this will **only** work if you do not have duplicate table names.

The other option is to change the schema dynamically before running the query, e.g.:

```
set schema 'schema_one';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer !!. I have same tables in multiple schemas. So I will go for second option. I am using JPAResository inected via Spring to store my entities. So to run above query which object I would use? Is it EntityManager?